# Fetch rows with column matching a criteria and send them by email (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

The need here is to have a minimum qty set in a column and once the inventory has items' qtys equal to or below that, have an email sent once a day with the rows fetched.
I have the below script working for another purpose, but this sends an email with one row at a time, while we now need to have the rows fetched and sent in one email (HTML format is ideal).

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pedidos");
  var startRow = 7;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A7:s3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 25)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (rowData[13] === "Ativo") {
    var emailAddress = "";  // First column
    var update = rowData[12];
    var NumPedido = rowData[0];
    var Cliente = rowData[1];
    var UF = rowData[3];
    var Produto = rowData[4];
    var TotaldoPedido = rowData[7];
    var NumNF = rowData[8];
    var Status = rowData[13];
    var Obs = rowData[16];
    var DataAgenda = rowData[11];
    var senha = rowData[15];
    var respons = rowData[17];
    var message =  "<HTML><BODY>"
    //+ "<P>Dear " + firstname + ","
    //+ "<br /><br />"
    + "<P>Status do Pedido " + NumPedido + ", do cliente " + Cliente + " foi atualizado! Veja abaixo:"
    + "<brr /><br />"
    + "<br>Data da Atualização:  </b>" + update + "<br />" 
    + "<br>Nº do Pedido:  </b>" + NumPedido + "<br />" 
    + "<br>Cliente:  </b>" + Cliente + UF + "<br />" 
    + "<br>Produto:  </b>" + Produto + "<br />" 
    + "<br>Nº da NF:  </b>" + NumNF + "<br />"  
    + "<br>Status: </b>" + Status + "<br />"  
    + "<br>Senha:  </b>" + senha + "<br />"  
    + "<br>Observações: </b>" + Obs + "<br />" 
    + "<br>Responsável: </b>" + respons + "<br />" 
    + "<br /><br />"    
    + "<br>Clique para explorar detalhes, ou para atualizar o status: </b>" + "" + "<br />" 
    + "<br /><br />"  
    + "</HTML></BODY>";      
    var emailAtivo = rowData[18];    
    if (emailAtivo != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[13] === "Ativo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Status do Pedido " + NumPedido + " do " + Cliente + " " + UF + " atualizado";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress, 
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message
  });

  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 19).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
//}
```

}
}

---

Here is the updated script:
        function sendTableEmail() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Estoque-Almox - ADB");

```
  // Get your table data
  var startRow = 7;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 14); // Fetch the range of cells A7:D
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var minimum = sheet.getRange("n7:n32").getValue(); // Minimum quantity to check against

  // Loop through the data to build your table
  var message = "<html><body><table style=\"text-align:center\"><tr><th>Código</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Qtd(Cx)</th><th>Estoque Mín. (Cx)</th></tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var Code = rowData[4];
    var Description = rowData[5];
    var InventoryUnit = rowData[10];
    var InventoryBox = rowData[11];
    var InventoryPallet = rowData[12];
    //var MinQty = rowData[13];
    //if (minimum >= 31) {
      if (InventoryBox <= minimum) {
        //var valueA = rowData[0];
        //var valueB = rowData[1];
        message += "<tr><td>"+Code+"</td><td>"+Description+"</td><td>"+InventoryBox+"</td><td>"+minimum+"</td></tr>";
      //} 
    }
  }
  message += "</table></body></html>";
  var subject = "Alerta de Estoque Mín. na Expedição";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "EMAIL", 
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

...and this is the the result received in my email:
[image]
It's bringing decimal digits (4th Column) which it shouldn't and the 5th column displays 30, whilst on the spreadsheet the formula's result is "" where there are no products listed.
Again, thanks a million for your help.

---

Sorry, here it goes:
[image]

So, if Column L <= Column N, then fetch the rows meeting this condition and send them in an email.

Comment: Ok. Well, what did you try already? You post code that works for a different purpose - how have you attempted to change it to meet this purpose?

Comment: Hi @tehhowch, I imagine it's a couple of lines to change/add to the script above, but I would have to learn some principles and I will, but for the need described above deadline wise, asking for help here is my best  bet.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to check the minimum quantities, or do you want to know how to put each row in one email?

Comment: @AntonioSantos false. We don't work for you, or so you can meet your deadline. If you have specific programming questions, we are happy to help you improve or fix your attempt at resolving it. We are not here to simply write working code instead of you trying to solve the issue.

Comment: @tehhowch, I guess this is for learning and helping, right? In my case, the result serves a purpose and the discussion here makes a solution available for others with a similar need. If you dont want to help, then dont waste yours and my time getting on the way.

Comment: Hello @Diego, I would just need to tweak the script so that it fetches the rows matching their criteria (in a certain column) and have it sent by email. Currently, it sends row by row. Thanks

Comment: @tehhowch, the code aboves needs a tweak and I dont know its principle so I can mplement myself. So my question requires an improvement/fix, as you stated above.

Comment: @AntonioSantos as a part of asking a question, your responsibility is to do research and make attempts to understand what is happening. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Note also that I mention we are happy to help improve or fix **your attempt**. If you don't attempt anything, you aren't showing that you value anyone's time but your own.

Comment: Good discussion. I've always worked with Foreign Trade, learned languages and I am learning programming languages now. Coming up with the code above already required a lot of study for someone coming from a different background. I've just stumbled upon a principle related question and had the community here as a source for help. The line between learning and using the solution for a work related purpose is close to none, I think. Am a little lost now.

Comment: @AntonioSantos I don't understand how you're trying to compare your minimums. (Showing a screenshot of your spreadsheet might help.) First of all, because you use `getValue()` instead of `getValues()`, you're only getting the value in `N7`. How should I know which minimum value corresponds to which product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand more clearly what you're doing now. Since the "minimums" are unique to each row, you can pull it when you initiate `dataRange`. To prevent the list from including blank values, check that the `Code` isn't blank before proceeding. To fix the decimal number, use `toFixed()` ([see docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp)). Lastly, just in case no email needs to be sent, I added a `sendEmail` boolean. If all your quantities are okay, no email will be sent.

```
function sendTableEmail() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Estoque-Almox - ADB");

  // Get your table data
  var startRow = 7;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 15); // Fetch the range, including the minimums
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  // Loop through the data to build your table
  var message = "<html><body><table style=\"text-align:center\"><tr><th>Código</th><th>Descrição</th><th>Qtd(Cx)</th><th>Estoque Mín. (Cx)</th></tr>";
  var sendEmail = false; // If there is content to send, will be set to true
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var Code = rowData[4];
    if (Code != "") { // Check for blank Code. If blank, then skip and don't add to the table.
      var Description = rowData[5];
      var InventoryUnit = rowData[10];
      var InventoryBox = rowData[11];
      var InventoryPallet = rowData[12];
      var minimum = rowData[13];
      if (InventoryBox <= minimum) {
        message += "<tr><td>"+Code+"</td><td>"+Description+"</td><td>"+Number(InventoryBox).toFixed(0)+"</td><td>"+minimum+"</td></tr>";
        sendEmail = true; // There is content to send!
      }
    }
  }
  message += "</table></body></html>";
  if (sendEmail) {
    var subject = "Alerta de Estoque Mín. na Expedição";
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "EMAIL", 
      subject: subject, 
      htmlBody: message
    });
  }
}
```

---

You haven't provided enough information for me to fix your attempt, so instead I'm providing you with an example based off what you have provided. The general principles are:

- Grab data from the sheet (work backwards from the [getValue or getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) methods)
- [Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) through the data using an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- Compare the data using [IF statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- Concatenate strings ([using + assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators))
- Create an [HTML table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

I hope this helps.

```
function sendTableEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pedidos");

  // Get your table data
  var startRow = 7;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4); // Fetch the range of cells A7:D
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var minimum = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue(); // Minimum quantity to check against

  // Loop through the data to build your table
  var message = "<html><body><table style=\"text-align:center\"><tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var status = rowData[3];
    var quantity = rowData[2];
    if (status == "Ativo") {
      if (quantity <= minimum) {
        var valueA = rowData[0];
        var valueB = rowData[1];
        message += "<tr><td>"+valueA+"</td><td>"+valueB+"</td><td>"+quantity+"</td><td>"+status+"</td></tr>";
      } 
    }
  }
  message += "</table></body></html>";
  var subject = "Email Subject";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS@DOMAIN.COM", 
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

This is what the spreadsheet looks like.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the code above. After I have implemented it, changing Min. Qty from a fix cell to a range, I get rows displaying values to compare inventory against even though the those cells contain only formulas.

Comment: Can you show you update your question and show your new code? Also, a screenshot of your spreadsheet would be great.

Comment: Just did, @Diego! Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioSantos I hope my revised response answers your question!

Comment: AWESOME @Diego! Works smoothly. Thanks a million and I have learned quite a bit here. Cheers!